# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. but i'm not calling any component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, object

if i call all discount price using map method. it perfectly work but i see in console and like this error are found. how to fix it

```
 <div className="priceCal flex flex-col items-center">
       <p style={{ fontSize: '1.5em' }} className='font-medium pt-3'>Total items: </p>
          {
            data.map((v, i)=>{
            return <p className='font-bold text-xl'>Rs. {v.DiscountPrice}</p>
             })
         }
</div>
```

[Click to view the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbQiK.png)

﻿

```
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:117 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Cart`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at p
    at Cart (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3393:74)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63733:5)
    at RouterMenu
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:140:81)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63666:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63146:5)
```

Comment: the `<p>` in your `data.map` needs a property called `key`. See [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more info

Comment: The answer is in your question title itself. Every React child in a list needs a key (irrespective of whether it's a Component or a *normal html element*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a key to the parent element of the return like this

```
return <p className='font-bold text-xl' key={i}>Rs. {v.DiscountPrice}</p>
```

But it's better to use a unique property of the object like `key={v.id}` if `id` exists

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over

```
data.map((v, i)=>{
        return <p className='font-bold text-xl'>Rs. {v.DiscountPrice}</p>
})
```

Just add a key to the return JSX

```
data.map((v, i)=>{
        return <p key={i} className='font-bold text-xl'>Rs. {v.DiscountPrice}</p>
})
```

If you have a unique identifier in the v object, use that

Refer => https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: Where does `index` come from?

Comment: @charlietfl The index is the item index. Please refer to the reference link posted in the answer. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys.

Comment: Look at the code you wrote. `index` and `i` are not the same thing. In your actual answer ( not the support docs) `index` is undefined

Comment: Got it @charlietfl. I missed it. Updating the answer.